# how to load multiple xml files using spring util-properties

Tags: spring, properties, loading

I have multiple sqlQueries.xml files e.g sqlQueries.xml, sqlQueriesAB.xml, sqlQueriesBC.xml and i want to load all of them using below tag but it seems that  only supports loading one file only.

`<util:properties id="sqlQueries" location="classpath:sqlQueries.xml" />`  - This is working. in this case, i have moved all entries from other sqlQueries*.xml to this file.

`<util:properties id="sqlQueries" location="classpath*:sqlQueries*.xml" />`  - not working..it says that, [classpath*:sqlQueries*.xml] doesn't exists.

`<util:properties id="sqlQueries" location="classpath*:sqlQueries.xml,sqlQueriesAB.xml, sqlQueriesBC.xml" />` - this is not working. Error same as above.

Can someone tell me how can i load multiple .xml file using util-properties or other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:helloWorld.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:helloWorld1.properties</value>
                    </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

should work for xml file too I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a xml file which contains or imports all other sql query files.
Create `queries.xml` file. And add all xml files in it.

```
<import resource="sqlQueries.xml"/>     
<import resource="sqlQueriesAB.xml"/>
<import resource="sqlQueriesBC.xml"/>
```

Then load `queries.xml` file in app context.

```
<util:properties id="sqlQueries" location="classpath:queries.xml" />
```

Try this.